# Can Markov chain represent a non-stationary random process?

Tags: probability, markov-process, stationary-processes

I guess I will just talk about the discrete case and below is my current understanding of things.

Markov chain: A discrete random variable A has several states $A_{0}, A_{1}, A_{2} ... $ over a discrete time t measured in time steps. The probability $T_{i\rightarrow j}$ of reaching a particular state $A_{j}$ in next time step depends only on the identity of the current state $A_{i}$. For example whenever the current state is $A_{0}$, the probabilities for reaching $A_{0}, A_{1}, A_{2}$ ... are always the same regardless of any past states of A.

Non-stationary process: The probability distribution of states of a discrete random variable A (without knowing any information of current/past states of A) depends on discrete time t. For example, temperature is usually higher in summer than winter. Therefore, the probability distribution of possible temperature over time is a non-stationary random process.

My question is: Can a Markov chain accurately represent a non-stationary process?

Does a Markov chain always represent a stationary random process?

Comment: This should be simple, but I haven't learned enough about probability ... Oh, by the way are my definitions correct?

Comment: What you want is a non-homogeneous Markov chain.

Comment: @RobertIsrael What is a non-homogeneous Markov chain?

Comment: Or less drastically, one with a non-stationary starting distribution.

Comment: @kimchilover will that eventually reach a stationary distribution?

Comment: If any state can reach any other, yes.  Changing subject: you can model seasonal behavior by having a bunch of Jan states that only transition to Feb states that can only transition to Mar states, and so on.

Comment: @kimchilover Hmm. that one is fun : ) It looks like transforming a non-stationary process into a series of stationary processes that each works only on a particular month of the year. Like one for Jan of 1950 and Jan of 1951 and Jan of... Then one for each month. Did I remember that correctly?

Comment: There is something called *cyclostationarity* that covers this sort of thing.  If, as Robert Israel suggested, you make the transition matrix depend on the time you can get a somewhat similar effect.  In fact, I think mine is a special case of his.

Answer (score 2):

(2017-09-01 21:00: This answer just received a revenge downvote. Oh well...)

> *Summary:* Homogenous transitions $\ne$ Stationary distribution.

Consider a *homogenous* Markov chain: this is a Markov chain $(X_n)$ such that the transition probabilities $q(x,y)=P(X_{n+1}=y\mid X_n=x)$ do not depend on $n$. In general, such a condition does not imply that the process $(X_n)$ is *stationary*, that is, that $\nu_n(x)=P(X_n=x)$ does not depend on $n$. Actually, the only case when this happens is if the initial distribution of the Markov chain is *stationary*, that is, if $\nu_0q=\nu_0$.

Comment: At the very end, you write $\nu_0 q = \nu_0$.  I'm having some trouble understanding what's meant here.  In the finite state case, I think $q$ is a matrix, and $v_0$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$?  But I'm not sure how to interpret it for the general case (i.e. possibly continuous, infinitely many states)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can for example let the state number encode the previously visited modes. For example a two letter alphabet with memory of 2 slots has $2^2 = 4$ possible states that the last two seen symbols were:

1. AA
2. AB
3. BA
4. BB

Now you can decide if you want the chain to map states of 2 old symbols to 2 new ones or just to one new symbol at a time. This will decide how many degrees of freedom your transition matrix (or conditional probability space) will have. If you choose just one new then you can figure out that states 1 and 3 can only end up in 1 or 2 since one of the symbols will "remain in the pipeline", reducing the possibilities for transitions.

Comment: If I keep the original states without doing any kind of embedding, can a Markov chain represent a non-stationary random process?

Comment: If you already have a chain that only maps from current to next symbol (one at a time), then you will need to expand or embed the set of states to carry the memory somehow. You can do this systematically for example with Kronecker products if you want.

Comment: Wait. Non-stationarity of random process implies memory and that the process is non-Markovian?

Comment: No it doesn't, I misread your question. Well you can just change the matrix encoding transition probabilities over time already if you don't want any memory but just allow the probabilities to change as functions of time. If it is called a Markov Chain... So you are more interested in what name it has than what kind of stuff and how to build with it?

Comment: Using transition probabilities that change over time certainly can represent non-stationary random process. I am not sure if that is necessary though. Is there a mathematical proof at some place that says Non-stationarity implies non-Markovian? I really haven't took any probability class and learned things on my own...

Comment: As far as I remember non-stationarity just means the transition probabilities can change over time; that they are allowed to be (non-constant) functions of time. But I am not exactly a stationary process myself at the moment, so my old schoolbooks are not with me to check.